# Converter linha para coluna

Tags: mysql, sql-select, pivot

Tenho um campo chamado "Turno" do tipo `STRING`, armazenando dados em MySql desta forma: `'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'`

Preciso que esta linha string se transforme (faça transposição) em uma unica coluna (neste caso, seria o inverso do que o `GROUP_CONCAT` faz), sendo esta uma tabela temporária ou não, ficando assim:

```
Turno
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Como solucionar?

Answer (score 2):

Você precisar realizar um PIVOT. Em outros bancos de dados, como SQL Server, é mais fácil fazer isso. No MySQL você precisa criar expressões agregadas, [como por exempo essa que criei no Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fac6a/9), dá uma olhada por lá.

Basicamente, para o universo de dados abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE Turnos (`id` int, `turno` int);

INSERT INTO Turnos (`id`, `turno`)
VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (1, 1),
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (1, 3),
  (1, 5),
  (1, 5),
  (1, 6),
  (1, 6),
  (1, 7),
  (1, 9),
  (1, 9),
  (1, 9)
;
```

Efetuamos a consulta como segue:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(CASE turno WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1',
  SUM(CASE turno WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2',
  SUM(CASE turno WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3',
  SUM(CASE turno WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4',
  SUM(CASE turno WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5',
  SUM(CASE turno WHEN 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6',
  SUM(CASE turno WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7',
  SUM(CASE turno WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8',
  SUM(CASE turno WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9'
  FROM Turnos
```

Chegando ao resultado almejado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tiago, acho que não me expressei bem na hora de criar esta pergunta... O valor STRING '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9' (na qual nunca serão valores iguais, ou seja, será dinâmico) originalmente sendo uma ARRAY em PHP, está como parâmetro de entrada em uma Stored Procedure. A partir daí, iria precisar transformar esta ARRAY em TABELA, fazendo a transposição em uma coluna, inserindo de cada elemento que está separado por virgula individualmente. Para que posteriormente, possa fazer o tratamento em um CURSOR. Ficando Assim: Turno 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Answer (score 1):

Após ler seu comentário na resposta do Tiago, creio que a solução seja muito parecida com a da sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9200/227).

Ao invés de transformar um "array" de valores em uma tabela para percorrer com um cursor, você pode usar os comandos de tratamento de String do MySQL para percorrer os itens.

Veja o exemplo:

```sql
CREATE procedure insere_array(array text)
begin
    declare elemento text;
    declare pos int;
    declare pos_ant int;
    set pos = LOCATE(',', array);
    set pos_ant = 1;
    delete from tabela;
    while pos > 0 do

       set elemento = substring(array, pos_ant, pos - pos_ant);
       if length(trim(elemento)) > 0 then
          insert into tabela (item) values (elemento);
       end if;

       set pos_ant = pos + 1;
       set pos = LOCATE(',', array, pos_ant);

    end while;
    if pos_ant <= length(array) then
        set elemento = substring(array, pos_ant, length(array) - pos_ant + 1);
        if length(trim(elemento)) > 0 then
            insert into tabela (item) values (elemento);
        end if;
    end if;
end//
```

### [Veja o Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51499/2)