# Como obter valores separados por "<BR>" no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-select

A ideia é simples...preciso obter valores de uma tabela (efetuando SELECT) que estão separados por `<BR>` de um campo STRING e depois armazenar em uma tabela, inserindo cada separação, um registro.

**Exemplo 1:**

**Registro:**

```
"Enviado para Cotação por Nemoreni Oliveira em 03-12-2013 13:46:22<br>Cotado por Edimar Nunes Pereira em 03-01-2014 13:52:14<br>"
```

**Registro esperado:**

```
"Enviado para Cotação por Nemoreni Oliveira em 03-12-2013 13:46:22"
"Cotado por Edimar Nunes Pereira em 03-01-2014 13:52:14"
```

**Exemplo 2:**

**Registro:**

```
"Enviado para Cotação por Rosimar da Silva Ribeiro em 09-12-2013 13:17:13<br>Cotado por Edimar Nunes Pereira em 09-12-2013 16:26:21<br><br>Reavaliado por: Edimar Nunes Pereira. Em: 2013-12-27 16:45:05<br>Motivo: incluir o ultimo item da NF na sc  de compra.<br><br>Enviado para Cotação por Rosimar da Silva Ribeiro em 27-12-2013 16:59:39<br>Enviado para Cotação por Rosimar da Silva Ribeiro em 27-12-2013 17:00:24<br>Cotado por Edimar Nunes Pereira em 30-12-2013 08:14:26<br>Enviado para Cotação por Rosimar da Silva Ribeiro em 02-01-2014 14:03:27<br>Cotado por Edimar Nunes Pereira      em 02-01-2014 14:05:23<br>"
```

**Registro esperado:**

```
"Enviado para Cotação por Rosimar da Silva Ribeiro em 09-12-2013 13:17:13"
"Cotado por Edimar Nunes Pereira em 09-12-2013 16:26:21"
"Reavaliado por: Edimar Nunes Pereira. Em: 2013-12-27 16:45:05"
"Motivo: incluir o ultimo item da NF na sc  de compra."
"Enviado para Cotação por Rosimar da Silva Ribeiro em 27-12-2013 16:59:39"
"Enviado para Cotação por Rosimar da Silva Ribeiro em 27-12-2013 17:00:24"
"Cotado por Edimar Nunes Pereira em 30-12-2013 08:14:26"
"Enviado para Cotação por Rosimar da Silva Ribeiro em 02-01-2014 14:03:27"
"Cotado por Edimar Nunes Pereira em 02-01-2014 14:05:23"
```

Comment: A pergunta está confusa, mas olhando seu título original me ocorreu o seguinte: você quer que o MySQL devolva as quebras de linha substituídas por `<br>`, é isso?

Comment: Ainda está um pouco confuso, tem como você colocar como exemplo o select que você tem hoje para tentarmos entender um pouco melhor a situação?

Comment: É obrigatório fazer isso pelo banco ou pode ser feito por alguma outra linguaguem?

Comment: A separação está na parte da STRING "<BR>", assim, preciso obter os dados que estão entre eles. Quando postei a pergunta, o "<BR>" foi excluído por algum motivo.

Comment: E como faço para armazenar estes registros em uma tabela temporária em linhas separadas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Substituir quebras de linha por `<br/>`

Você pode utilizar a função `REPLACE` para isso. Exemplo:

```sql
select REPLACE(campo,'\n','<br />') from tabela
```

Note que usei `\n` como separador de linha, porém isso pode variar conforme o sistema operacional que envia os dados para o MySQL.

### [Demo no Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/33486)

## Dividir o conteúdo por quebras

No MySQL não há uma função `SPLIT` ou algo parecido que possa transforar uma única coluna em várias.

Existem, no entanto, algumas soluções paliativas com o uso de comandos com `SUBSTRING`, `LOCATE` e `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, como descritas [nesta pergunta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705271/mysql-split-string-function-split-str-does-not-work-with-left-join-any-issue) e também nos [comentários da documentação do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html).

Você pode criar uma procedure que procure a primeira ocorrência da quebra de linha, pegue o texto antes dela e inclua onde você quiser. Coloque isso num laço e faça até não sobrarem mais itens.

Fiz um exemplo básico:

```sql
CREATE procedure split(texto text)
begin
    declare trecho text;
    declare pos int;
    declare pos_ant int;
    set pos = LOCATE('\n', texto);
    set pos_ant = 1;
    delete from linhas;
    while pos > 0 do

       set trecho = substring(texto, pos_ant, pos - pos_ant);
       if length(trim(trecho)) > 0 then
          insert into linhas (linha) values (trecho);
       end if;

       set pos_ant = pos + 1;
       set pos = LOCATE('\n', texto, pos_ant);

    end while;
    if pos_ant <= length(texto) then
        set trecho = substring(texto, pos_ant, length(texto) - pos_ant + 1);
        if length(trim(trecho)) > 0 then
            insert into linhas (linha) values (trecho);
        end if;
    end if;
end//
```

### [Veja no Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1382/1)

Após ver a atualização na pergunta, fiz um novo exemplo usando `<br>`:

```sql
CREATE procedure split(texto text)
begin
    declare trecho text;
    declare pos int;
    declare pos_ant int;
    set pos = LOCATE('<br>', texto);
    set pos_ant = 1;
    delete from linhas;
    while pos > 0 do

       set trecho = substring(texto, pos_ant, pos - pos_ant);
       if length(trim(trecho)) > 0 then
          insert into linhas (linha) values (trecho);
       end if;

       set pos_ant = pos + 4;
       set pos = LOCATE('<br>', texto, pos_ant);

    end while;
    if pos_ant <= length(texto) then
        set trecho = substring(texto, pos_ant, length(texto) - pos_ant + 1);
        if length(trim(trecho)) > 0 then
            insert into linhas (linha) values (trecho);
        end if;
    end if;
end//
```

### [Veja no Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf88d/1)

## Considerações

Esse tipo de tratamento é feito de forma mais adequada em uma linguagem de programação completa como Java, C#, PHP, Python e assim por diante. Talvez seja melhor criar um pequeno programa para se encarregar da tarefa.

Comment: Perfeito! Como uma luva! Muito obrigado!

Comment: @mcardoso Legal! Se resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta.

Comment: @mcardoso Vi que haviam alguns bugs nas rotinas relacionadas a recuperar o trecho adequado do texto. Acabei de corrigi-los.

Answer (score 2):

Troque o `<br>` por `\n` utlizando a função [replace()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) do mysql

```
SELECT replace(campo, '<br>', '\n') FROM tabela
```

Comment: blz! E como faço para armazenar estes registros em uma tabela temporária em linhas separadas?

Comment: @mcardoso, acho que você vai ter que fazer um script em alguma linguagem de programação para deixar este retorno exatamente do jeito que você quer.

Answer (score 1):

No `SELECT`, você pode concatenar ao valor da coluna uma string que sua aplicação entenda como quebra de linha (`<br />` ou `\n`).

No mysql você pode fazer isso com o `CONCAT()`

```
    SELECT CONCAT(a.nome, '<br />') as nome from registros a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puderes criar um ficheiro no servidor da base de dados, usa o [SELECT ... INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/...'
LINES TERMINATED BY '<br>\n'
```

Depois usas o ficheiro como input para insercoes com o [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/...'
INTO ...
```

*Atencao: metodo nao testado*