# Select com subquery transformando em coluna

Tags: mysql

Bem, eu não sabia como colocar o título...

Enfim, eu tenho a tabela **tblnotadisciplina** (segue imagem) que vai armazenar notas de alunos de um determinado período. Essas notas tem um tipo de avaliação (1-Trabalho, 2-Prova). Eu quero realizar uma consulta onde eu receba os nomes do aluno (usando join, claro), nota 1 (Trabalho) e nota 2 (prova), exemplo

Nome     nota1     nota2 
Aluno1   10        10

Desde já agradeço!

[image: tblnotadisciplina]

Comment: Seria isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7999/converter-linha-para-coluna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer uma soma condicional com `if`:

```
SELECT
   nomealuno
   SUM(IF(idavaliacao=1,nota,0)) AS trabalho,
   SUM(IF(idavaliacao=2,nota,0)) AS prova
FROM
   tblaluno a LEFT JOIN tblnotadisciplina b ON a.idmatricula = b.idmatricula 
GROUP BY
   tblaluno.idmatricula
```

Estou supondo que o agrupamento seja por matrícula, mas é simples você ajustar para o campo que quiser. A lógica é a mesma, só ajuste os campos conforme sua realidade.

Comment: Cara, muitíssimo obrigado! Serviu como um luva.