# Como transformo algumas linhas em colunas?

Tags: sql

Tenho essa base de dados com perguntas e respostas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E preciso criar um view que as perguntas e respostas fiquem dispostas desse jeito.

.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um amigo falou de um tal de pivot mas não consigo fazer ele funcionar

Comment: Que base de dados está utilizar

Comment: Qual o seu objetivo com essa consulta? Quantas mais perguntas/respostas tiver mais colunas terá... se tiver 500 perguntas/respostas terá 1.000 colunas a mais!

Comment: São 12 perguntas, são resultados de uma pesquisa de satisfação de atendimento

Comment: O resultado vai ser consumido totalmente dentro do sql? Ou pode ser impresso por um sistema externo?

Comment: Totalmente dentro do sql, pensei em fazer um script em java pra processar a tabela q eu queria, mas, toda atualização do banco ia ter q ser processada por esse script e é inviável .

Comment: Esse formato não me parece legível para as pessoas, e também não é útil para ser aplicado em relatórios... logo não faz sentido querer os dados assim. Qual é seu objetivo ?

Comment: Esse recurso chamamos de "pivot table", mas no seu caso me parece que você está mais desnormalizando a tabela com esse resultado, e assim como @RovannLinhalis mencionou parece sem sentido

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Converter linha para coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7999/converter-linha-para-coluna)

Comment: Na realidade acho que é mais correto é você dizer o que você quer fazer com o resultado, assim podemos sugerir soluções melhores...

Comment: Meu orientador me pediu pra criar essa view usando sql para que eu pode-se posteriormente criar um dashboard usando qlik sense, como os dados são constantemente atualizados, usar um script é inviável por conta do custo de processamento, e o exemplo que mostrei a vocês é simplório, existem outras colunas que possuem o texto da pergunta e outras informações.

Fiquei sabendo desse pivot table, e achei isso https://www.devmedia.com.br/pivotando-dados-no-sql-parte-01/9724 mas não me satisfaz muito uma vez que eu não consigo separar em colunas.

Comment: Acredito que usando INNER JOINS e SubSelection consiga da um jeito, porém, deixa  a requisição muito grande e complicada e não estou sendo feliz, e nem sei se é realmente possível.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Tenho essa base de dados com perguntas e respostas
>
>   E preciso criar um view que as perguntas e respostas fiquem dispostas desse jeito.*

Lucas, faltou nos informar qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados que está a utilizar.

Como o número de perguntas e respostas é fixo, eis sugestão que utiliza o pivô clássico:

```
-- código #1
SELECT id_entrevistado, 
       1 as [pergunta 1], 
       max(case when id_pergunta = 1 then resposta end) as [resposta 1],
       2 as [pergunta 2], 
       max(case when id_pergunta = 2 then resposta end) as [resposta 2],
       ... acrescentar bloco de 3 a 11
       12 as [pergunta 12], 
       max(case when id_pergunta = 12 then resposta end) as [resposta 12]
  from Perguntas_Respostas
  group by id_entrevistado;
```

Complemente o código para as perguntas de 3 a 11; basta copiar o bloco abaixo, substituindo *n* pelo número da pergunta/resposta.

```
   n as [pergunta n], 
   max(case when id_pergunta = n then resposta end) as [resposta n],
```

Comment: Muito trabalho para resultado questionável. O template que você propôs é muito melhor do que o que eu havia imaginado, mas a questão conforme apresentada lembra muito mais o problema XY.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Boa tarde. Procurei atender literalmente ao pedido do Lucas, pois não sei como o Qlik Sense necessita dos dados. Mas, em princípio a coluna [pergunta n] me parece inútil...

Comment: Então pessoal, eu tinha entendido o problema errado, mas foi essencial pra resolver o trecho que o @JoséDiz respondeu pra resolver o problema, Obrigado a todos.