# Consulta PIVOT no Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tenho uma consulta em SQL Server utilizando PIVOT que me retorna os dados em coluna conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A query é essa:

```
SELECT * FROM(
          SELECT ftd.DateAndTime AS dt,  ftd.Val AS Val, CONVERT(VARCHAR, ttd.TagIndex) as tagIndex 
          FROM FloatTableHour ftd INNER JOIN TagTableHour ttd ON ttd.TagIndex = ftd.TagIndex  
          WHERE ftd.Marker = 'S' 
          AND ftd.DateAndTime BETWEEN '2019-01-14 00:00:000' AND '2019-01-14 23:59:059' 
          AND ttd.TagName IN(
                            '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_NR', 
                            '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_D', 
                            '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdHou', 
                            '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdMin', 
                            '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrd', 
                            '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrdMin', 
                            '[AGUA]LT_MAX_DA[0]', '[AGUA]LT_MIN_DA[0]')) 
                            teste PIVOT(SUM(Val) FOR tagIndex in([9], [8], [16], [17], [30], [18], [0], [4]) ) colunas 
            ORDER BY dt
```

Porém, devido a limitação do banco de 10GB, estou fazendo a migração para o Mysql e preciso efetuar a mesma consulta, consegui fazer até este ponto:

```
SELECT ftd.DateAndTime AS dt,  ftd.Val AS Val, ttd.TagIndex as tagIndex FROM FloatTableHour ftd 
            INNER JOIN TagTableHour ttd ON ttd.TagIndex = ftd.TagIndex 
            AND ftd.DateAndTime 
            BETWEEN '2019-01-14 00:00:000'
            AND '2019-01-14 23:59:059' 
            AND ttd.TagName IN(
                                '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_NR', 
                                '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_D', 
                                '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdHou', 
                                '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdMin', 
                                '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrd', 
                                '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrdMin', 
                                '[AGUA]LT_MAX_DA[0]', 
                                '[AGUA]LT_MIN_DA[0]')
```

Porém seu retorno fica como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7999/converter-linha-para-coluna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talvez assim?

```
SELECT      ftd.DateAndTime                                             AS dt
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN ttd.TagIndex = 9 THEN ftd.Val ELSE 0 END)     AS '9'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN ttd.TagIndex = 8 THEN ftd.Val ELSE 0 END)     AS '8'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN ttd.TagIndex = 16 THEN ftd.Val ELSE 0 END)    AS '16'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN ttd.TagIndex = 17 THEN ftd.Val ELSE 0 END)    AS '17'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN ttd.TagIndex = 30 THEN ftd.Val ELSE 0 END)    AS '30'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN ttd.TagIndex = 18 THEN ftd.Val ELSE 0 END)    AS '18'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN ttd.TagIndex = 0 THEN ftd.Val ELSE 0 END)     AS '0'
        ,   SUM(CASE WHEN ttd.TagIndex = 4 THEN ftd.Val ELSE 0 END)     AS '4'
FROM        FloatTableHour  ftd 
INNER JOIN  TagTableHour    ttd ON  ttd.TagIndex = ftd.TagIndex 
WHERE       ftd.DateAndTime BETWEEN '2019-01-14 00:00:000' AND '2019-01-14 23:59:059' 
        AND ttd.TagName IN  (
                                '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_NR', 
                                '[AGUA]FT[0].Tot_D', 
                                '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdHou', 
                                '[AGUA]POCO[0].IntTotPrdMin', 
                                '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrd', 
                                '[AGUA]POCO[0].OutEfePrdMin', 
                                '[AGUA]LT_MAX_DA[0]', 
                                '[AGUA]LT_MIN_DA[0]'
                            )
GROUP BY    ftd.DateAndTime
```

Comment: João, exatamente isso, ficou show. Executei aqui, deu um erro aqui "[9]", porém bastou apenas colocar o 9 entre aspas simples. Vou estudar aqui pra entender melhor.

Comment: Resposta editada para colocar as aspas simples!

Comment: Fui executar na base real e percebi que trouxe apenas um resultado somando todos os valores, porém preciso demonstrar os valores separados conforme primeira imagem.

Comment: Pois, faltou uma coisa muito importante, o `GROUP BY`! Resposta editada.

Comment: Verdade, cara preciso estudar mais MySql, muito obrigado.

Comment: De nada, sempre às ordens! Aproveite e dê um UP na resposta :)